# How to change Windows 10 projector settings?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

The projector shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> is a nice way to switch between different monitors.

[image]

The problem with this is that it doesn't respect what you say is your main monitor.

[image]

So when I select main screen only, it will use my middle monitor. This is not what I want, I would like to have monitor 3 as my "main" monitor.
Same as when I select second screen only, I would actually like to only use monitor 2.

Is there a way in Windows<sup>(1)</sup> to change which monitors are used as your "main" and/or "secondary" monitor?

<sup>(1): The order seems to be based on which port you use on the video-card but since I have a HDMI, DVI and VGA connector I can't change ports</sup>

Comment: @CharlieRB 3, 1, 2 is actually the physical order of the monitors. So when I extend the desktop over all three, the mouse can move LTR. I can set monitor 3 as main monitor in this extended setup, but what I can't do is ONLY use monitor 3 through Windows projector settings.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to ask if you selected #3 and check marked "Make this my main display" on the display settings screen?

Comment: Yes, but as a side-effect this will also switch your projector setting. It doesn't seem possible to use "Main screen only" with anything other than monitor 1.

Comment: Agreed. Windows has always been somewhat limited when it comes to multiple monitor configuration. You may have to look at third party solutions like Display Fusion. An then, I am not even sure it will do what you want.